# Attachmate Windows XP and Windows 7 cannot add EXTRACOM.tlb

Tags: .net, com, screen-scraping, tlbimp

A .NET 2.0  project has a reference to an Windows XP which was using "EXTRA" ,  but with Windows 7 , The Attachmate software is using Attachmate Reflection , and It seems that people are told to get rid of "EXTRA" and replace with "EXTRACOM"

I'm still researching it, but I wanted to see if anyone had this issue.

EXTRACOM.tlb   I try to add and I get a

```
  "A reference to EXTRACOM could not be added,        ... was exported from a .NET assembly and cannot be added as a reference.

 "Add a reference to the .NET assembly instead"
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Tom:

When adding the reference, use the Browse option to find EXTRACOM.dll (not EXTRACOM.tlb) in Reflection's installation directory.  Note that if you're using the latest Reflection, adding the reference will require using ".NET Framework 4" as your Target.  You'll want to change your project's Target first and then add the reference (if you add the reference and then change the Target, things can sometimes get confused).

Good luck!